# Forcing PG to use index with timerange. Works on small resultset, doesn't work on bigger sets

Tags: postgresql

**Edited**: added Explain Analyze

---

I've got the following table (simplified for example):

```
CREATE TABLE public.streamscombined
(
    eventtype text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    payload jsonb,
    clienttime bigint, //as millis from epoch
)
```

And a b-tree compound index on `clienttime + eventtype`

---

**Correct use of index when index prunes a lot of rows**

Doing a query of the following format correctly uses the index with a `clienttime` that filters a lot of documents. e.g.:

```
explain SELECT * FROM streamscombined WHERE eventtype='typeA' AND clienttime <= 1522550900000 order by clienttime;
```

=>

```
Index Scan using "clienttime/type" on streamscombined  (cost=0.56..1781593.82 rows=1135725 width=583)
Index Cond: ((clienttime <= '1522540900000'::bigint) AND (eventtype = 'typeA'::text))
```

**Explain Analyze**

`Index Scan using "clienttime/type" on streamscombined  (cost=0.56..1711616.01 rows=1079021 width=592) (actual time=1.369..13069.861 rows=1074896 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((clienttime <= '1522540900000'::bigint) AND (eventtype = 'typeA'::text))
Planning time: 0.208 ms
Execution time: 13369.330 ms`

**RESULT:** streaming results I see data coming in within 100ms.

---

**Ignoring index when index prunes less rows**

However, if completely falls flat when relaxing the `clienttime`-condition e.g (adding 3 hours):

```
explain SELECT * FROM streamscombined WHERE eventtype='typeA' AND clienttime <= (1522540900000 + (3*3600*1000)) order by clienttime;
```

=>

```
Gather Merge  (cost=2897003.10..3192254.78 rows=2530552 width=583)
Workers Planned: 2
->  Sort  (cost=2896003.07..2899166.26 rows=1265276 width=583)
Sort Key: clienttime
->  Parallel Seq Scan on streamscombined  (cost=0.00..2110404.89 rows=1265276 width=583)
Filter: ((clienttime <= '1522551700000'::bigint) AND (eventtype = 'typeA'::text))
```

**Explain analyze**

`Gather Merge  (cost=2918263.39..3193771.83 rows=2361336 width=592) (actual time=72505.138..75142.127 rows=2852704 loops=1)
Workers Planned: 2
Workers Launched: 2
->  Sort  (cost=2917263.37..2920215.04 rows=1180668 width=592) (actual time=70764.052..71430.200 rows=950901 loops=3)
Sort Key: clienttime
Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 722336kB
->  Parallel Seq Scan on streamscombined  (cost=0.00..2176719.08 rows=1180668 width=592) (actual time=0.451..57458.888 rows=950901 loops=3)
Filter: ((clienttime <= '1522551700000'::bigint) AND (eventtype = 'typeA'::text))
Rows Removed by Filter: 7736119
Planning time: 0.109 ms
Execution time: 76164.816 ms`

**RESULT:** streaming results I've waited for > 5 minutes without any result.

---

This is likely because PG believes the index will not prune the resultset that much, so it will use a different strategy.

However, and this is key, it completely seems to ignore the fact that I want to order by `clienttime` and the index is giving me that for free.

Is there any way to force PG to use the index independent on the actual value for the `clienttime`-condition?

Comment: Why are you storing time in an integer column?

Comment: @wildplasser: I've been bitten before by timezone stuff. Wanted to avoid that altogether so went with millis from epoch. Would it make a difference to above problem?

Comment: No,it would not solve above problem, but it could make your life easier, IMO. Two questions: 1) what is the cardinality of the `eventtype` column? 2) what is the (expected) fraction of rows retrieved by the two queries? 3) `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` , please...

Comment: @wildplasser: 1) cardinality atm 6. Will grow to about 10. 2). See edit. Thanks

Comment: What is the setting for random_page_cost? `SHOW random_page_cost;`  You could also want to play with enable_seqscan, (and ,maybe, statistics_targets)

Comment: `random_page_cost = 4`.. Yeah was already playing with `set ENABLE_SEQSCAN = false`.. Seems to indeed result in better performance, but still a magnitude slower (and different query plan) than the correctly performing one.

Comment: Setting random_page_cost to a lower value (1.x) could help a bit.

Comment: `random_page_cost = 1` indeed solves it! Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: Never mind. Found it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS). Thanks a bunch wildplasser.

Comment: Also take a look at the other settings. They could also still have their "factory" default values.

Answer (score 0):

sorting result is cheap, index scan is expensive as it does many disk seeks.

a lower setting of ramdom_page_cost reduces the cost estimate for the index scan  resulting in index scans being used for larger result-sets.